# Bulding Tensorflow with bazel: including TensorRT headers

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, bazel, tensorrt

I am in the process of compiling tensorflow on my EC2 instance to enable native instruction sets. I am completely new to bazel and overwhelmed with how to configure the build.

The only issue I have is that the compilation cannot make use of the headers in the locally installed TensorRT I put at /usr/local/TensorRT-8.6.1.6

First I tried to add TensorRT-8.6.1.6/include in PATH, no go. Still couldn’t find the headers.

Then I tried adding bazel copt `-I/usr/lib/TensorRT-8.6.1.6/include`, it complained about “references a path outside of the execution root”.

Finally I tried to symlink that directory to inside the source and use `-ITensorRT-8.6.1.6/include` and the latest error is

```
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/stub/nvinfer_stub.cc':
  'TensorRT-8.6.1.6/include/NvInferRuntimeBase.h'
  'TensorRT-8.6.1.6/include/NvInferVersion.h'
  'TensorRT-8.6.1.6/include/NvInferRuntimePlugin.h'
```

I don’t know why it’s so incredibly difficult to link to such a common dependency of tensorflow as TensorRT. I don’t have enough knowledge in bazel to include those headers.

Comment: some times ```bazel clean --expunge``` will work and try checking the right installation prerequisites.

Comment: I had the same problem, seems if you include both cuda and TensorRT, it will include both lib directories but only the cuda include directory with headers. So I copied the (few) headers from TensorRT into the cuda include directory and it solved the issue.